# React - cuando utilizar ForwardRefExoticComponent y ForwardRefRenderFunction

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Estoy utilizando `react` con `typescript`, pero no me ha quedado muy claro el cuando es importante utilizar este tipo de componente.

¿Cuál es la diferencia y que problema cubre el tener estos tipos de componentes?